# how to get every single tweets with a certain hashtag using tweepy and twitter REST API

Tags: python, rest, twitter, tweepy

for a data visualization project I need to gather all tweets (would it be possible at all?) with a certain hashtag. for this purpose I am using the code below. it uses Tweepy and REST API. However, it only downloads up to around 2500 tweets or less. I was wondering how I can fix this limitation. is there a pro subscription or anything else i should purchase or how should I modify the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# this file is configured for rtl language and farsi characters

import sys
from key import *
import tweepy

#imported from the key.py file
API_KEY =KAPI_KEY
API_SECRET =KAPI_SECRET
OAUTH_TOKEN =KOAUTH_TOKEN
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET =KOAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET

auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,
                 wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

if not api:
    print("Can't Authenticate")
    sys.exit(-1)

def write_unicode(text, charset='utf-8'):
    return text.encode(charset)

searchQuery = "#کرونا"  # this is what we're searching for
maxTweets = 100000  # Some arbitrary large number
tweetsPerQry = 100  # this is the max the API permits
fName = 'Corona-rest8.txt'  # We'll store the tweets in a text file.

sinceId = None

max_id = -1
tweetCount: int = 0
print("Downloading max {0} tweets".format(maxTweets))
with open(fName, "wb") as f:
    while tweetCount < maxTweets:
        try:
            if max_id <= 0:
                if not sinceId:
                    new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery, count=tweetsPerQry)
                else:
                    new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery, count=tweetsPerQry,
                                            since_id=sinceId)
            else:
                if not sinceId:
                    new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery, count=tweetsPerQry,
                                            max_id=str(max_id - 1))
                else:
                    new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery, count=tweetsPerQry,
                                            max_id=str(max_id - 1),
                                            since_id=sinceId)
            if not new_tweets:
                print("No more tweets found")
                break
            for tweet in new_tweets:

                #print(tweet._json["created_at"])
                if str(tweet._json["user"]["location"])!="":
                    print(tweet._json["user"]["location"])
                myDict = json.dumps(tweet._json["text"], ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')+ "\n".encode('ascii')
                f.write(myDict)

            tweetCount += len(new_tweets)
            print("Downloaded {0} tweets".format(tweetCount))
            max_id = new_tweets[-1].id
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            # Just exit if any error
            print("some error : " + str(e))
            break
print("Downloaded {0} tweets, Saved to {1}".format(tweetCount, fName))
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`tweepy` API Reference for `api.search()`](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.search) provides a bit of color on this:

> Please note that Twitter’s search service and, by extension, the Search API is **not meant to be an exhaustive source of Tweets. Not all Tweets will be indexed or made available via the search interface.**

To answer your question directly, it is not possible to acquire an exhaustive list of tweets from the API (because of several limitations). However, a few scraping-based Python libraries are available to work around these API limitations, like @taspinar's [`twitterscraper`](https://github.com/taspinar/twitterscraper).